# how to get product price from different size selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

I want to scrape product information from this [page](https://boutique.cafebarista.ca/products/autentico?variant=18033459331137) . This product have three different size and price will be change if I select different size from drop-down section. Right now my scraper only can scrape default price after first time initially page load which is 35 for 1kg. How I will scrape price for 500g and 250g. here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#argument for incognito Chrome
#argument for incognito Chrome
option = Options()
option.add_argument("--incognito")


browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=option)
browser.get("https://boutique.cafebarista.ca/products/cremone?variant=18033418797121")

product_title = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@class="product-name"]')
long_description = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="product-landing-container"]')
price=browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="product-btn-price ProductPrice"]')

print(product_title.text,long_description.text,price.text)


browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\New folder\chromedriver.exe")
browser.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)

browser.get("https://boutique.cafebarista.ca/products/cremone?variant=18033418797121")

kg_button=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='w-dropdown-toggle-16']")
kg_button.click()
list =wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//nav[@id='w-dropdown-list-16']//a")))
kg_button.click()
for element in list:
     kg_button.click()
     actionChains = ActionChains(browser)
     actionChains.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

     price = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='ProductPrice']")
     print product_title.text
     print element.text
     print price.text


browser.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks Dipak. Your code giving me thies result 250g,500g,1kg but I need  price for 250g,500g and 1kg

Comment: please check updated solution  and confirm if its working as per expectation

Comment: yeah I accept it. what tool you used for find right xpath?

Comment: Xpath finder will be there

Comment: can please give me the link of xpath finder which you used for find right xpath

Comment: Its a chrome  extension

Answer (score 2):

With `.find_elements_by_css_selector` you can get each text without clicking the `weight` drop down first, this is the selector I mean:

```
nav[id="w-dropdown-list-16"] > a > div
```

And you can also click on each of these elements using `.execute_script`

Try following code:

```
driver.get('https://boutique.cafebarista.ca/products/autentico?variant=18033459331137')
weight_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('nav[id="w-dropdown-list-16"] > a > div')
for weight in weight_list:
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', weight)
    price = driver.find_element_by_id('ProductPrice').text
    print(weight.get_attribute('innerHTML') +' ' +price)
```

Comment: Thanks frianH. your code also worked. how did you find the right css selector? what tools you used for find this css ?

Comment: @FarhanAhmed Glad it worked, see here [CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) hope that helps